# Bootstrap CSS - product lineup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For the tablet view, there is a row with one product in a row instead of 3 in a row. How can I have solve this issue? Screenshot attached.

[image]

```
<div style="text-align: justify; padding-top: 10px;" class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
<?php $prdurl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).$_product->getData('configurable_image_url'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $prdurl; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
<br>
<?php echo $_product->getName();  ?>
<br>
<?php echo $_product->getbasic_sku();  ?>
<br>

<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code for this?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code. Thank you @kkaosninja

Comment: @Elvis Not good enough. We can't edit or work on code in a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks @MattD I added code.

Comment: @Elvis What aspect of the code you've provided is useful to anyone in helping you resolve the issue? It's completely different from what you've chosen to provide via your screenshot as well. This appears to be an issue with the markup, and likely not with your server side code. While I'm not terribly familiar with PHP myself, I doubt anyone could take the code you've provided and run it successfully. Please provide us with the relevant bits of code/markup so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the height difference of the div (containing the mobile pic and details). 
So for solving this problem you have to give a fixed height for all the div
and you can show more details using scroll

call a common class for all the div and gave this properties.

```
height: Y px(give appropriate value for the Y),
overflow: auto,
```

I think this will do the trick for you,
if you share the code i can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a mechanism to handle this: **[Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)**

Insert clearing elements at appropriate intervals to properly clear each column.